# Autopopulate textbox on combobox update in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am using a combobox in Ms Access, which on change will populate other textboxes. The code is like this:

```
Private Sub Combotxt_Change();
Me.Qtypetxt = Me.Combotxt.Column(1);
Me.PFtxt = Me.Combotxt.Column(2);
End Sub
```

In this, the first textbox i.e. Qtypetxt gets updated whereas PFtxt doens't.
Kindly help.

Comment: Are you sure that you have at least 3 columns in Combotxt? Columns numeration starts from 0. And also use AfterUpdate event, not Change.

Comment: Yes, I have 11 columns.
I used the same code in After update event. It is still not working.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the second update, look at the value of Me.Combotxt.Column(2) and Me.PFtxt.Is an error being thrown/caught?

Comment: I am done with that error. It is working now. Actually when I removed the field from control source, it started working.

Now I can populate all the textboxes. I wish to edit the data in the textbox and save it back into the table. Please guide regarding that.

Comment: So it really isn't working if the data does not save. You want to pull value from lookup and save but then allow users to edit the value? Binding textbox to destination field should accomplish that.